# How to use POST method in perl?

Tags: perl

I have to get all the links in a webpage but all the links are loaded using post method.

Please provide any solution to get all the links.

Comment: please show us what you've tried. this is not a build-me-my-program site...

Comment: You are supposed to have tried your best to solve the problem yourself before you post a request here. "Please provide any solution to get all the links" is very rude and the question suggests you are trying to get out of doing any work of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [LWP](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $linkid = "link identifier";

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $browser->post(
  'http://sitewithlinks/linkget.php',
  [
    'linkid'  => $linkid,
    'hidden' => 'somethinghidden'
  ],
);
die "Error: ", $response->status_line
 unless $response->is_success;

print "GOT THIS: $response->content";
```